# Selenium / click on "View More"-button not possible?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i try to click on the "Click More" - Button on this site:
https://www.hublot.com/en-ch/find-your-hublot/big-bang

[image]

using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
if __name__ == '__main__':
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
  srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         

  link = "https://www.hublot.com/en-ch/find-your-hublot/big-bang"
  driver.get (link)    
  waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]'))).click() 
  waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="modal__header_btn js_country_pop_up_close"]'))).click() 
  waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class,"pl_section__view-more")]'))).click()
```

But i get this error:

```
$ python temp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Fiverr\TRY\Lawfulwizard\temp.py", line 24, in <module>
    waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class,"pl_section__view-more")]'))).click() 
  File "C:\DEV\.venv\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Why is this button clicking not working and how can i do this?

Comment: If i go to that page an do a `document.querySelectorAll(".pl_section__view-more")` i get six nodes. are you shure you are selecting the correct button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the issue is below XPath expression in your code:

```
//button[contains(@class,"pl_section__view-more")]
```

This locates 7 elements as shown below:

[image]

Hence your script is not able to locate the desired element and perform the `click()`.

**SOLUTION:** Tweak your XPath expression to locate only one element as below.
Below XPath expression will locate the second <kbd>View more</kbd> button. If you want the third button then just change the number at the end to `[3]` and so on.

```
(//button[contains(@class,"pl_section__view-more")])[2]
```

Change the below line:

```
waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class,"pl_section__view-more")]'))).click()
```

To:

```
waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//button[contains(@class,"pl_section__view-more")])[2]'))).click()
```

**SECOND ISSUE'S SOULTION**: After you change the XPath expression as above, you may not get `timeoutexception`, however you may get `EelementClickIntercepted` exception, if yes, perform click using javascript as shown below:

```
viewMoreBtn = waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//button[contains(@class,"pl_section__view-more")])[2]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", viewMoreBtn)
```